# Request Data show The same results everyday, when it supposed to be different

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager, android-notifications

I created a notification to show released movie and today's reminder. I have  method for repeating alarm, but the notification only shows up whenever I turn "ON" the alarm by SwitchPreferences. What I want here is to show notifications every single day and every movie's that being release when I just set the alarm to "ON" once. From my case here, I have to set the alarm on and on to get the notifications, but it supposed to call the notifications or request the data when the onReceive() function in BroadcastReceiver() class being called. Summarize, I just want to turn ON the alarm once and then the method will check the data from api if it's match to the date requested every single day

**Here is my AppCompatPref.java:**

```
public class AppCompatPref extends PreferenceActivity {


private AppCompatDelegate mAppCompatDelegate;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    getDelegate().installViewFactory();
    getDelegate().onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

public ActionBar getSupportActionBar() {
    return getDelegate().getSupportActionBar();
}

public void invalidateOptionsMenu() {
    getDelegate().invalidateOptionsMenu();
}

private AppCompatDelegate getDelegate() {
    if (mAppCompatDelegate == null) {
        mAppCompatDelegate = AppCompatDelegate.create(this, null);
    }
    return mAppCompatDelegate;
}

public void setSupportActionBar(@Nullable Toolbar toolbar) {
    getDelegate().setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
}

@Override
public MenuInflater getMenuInflater() {
    return getDelegate().getMenuInflater();
}

@Override
public void setContentView(@LayoutRes int layoutResID) {
    getDelegate().setContentView(layoutResID);
}

@Override
public void setContentView(View view) {
    getDelegate().setContentView(view);
}

@Override
public void setContentView(View view, ViewGroup.LayoutParams params) {
    getDelegate().setContentView(view, params);
}

@Override
public void addContentView(View view, ViewGroup.LayoutParams params) {
    getDelegate().addContentView(view, params);
}

@Override
protected void onTitleChanged(CharSequence title, int color) {
    super.onTitleChanged(title, color);
    getDelegate().setTitle(title);
}

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getDelegate().onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
protected void onPostResume() {
    super.onPostResume();
    getDelegate().onPostResume();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    getDelegate().onStop();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    getDelegate().onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    getDelegate().onDestroy();
}
```

}

**Here's my MovieDailyReminder:**

```
public class MovieDailyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

private void sendNotification(Context context, String title, String desc, int id) {
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(
            Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Intent mIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);

    PendingIntent mPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, id, mIntent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    Uri uriTone = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notifications_black_24dp)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(desc)
            .setContentIntent(mPendingIntent)
            .setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, android.R.color.transparent))
            .setVibrate(new long[]{1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000})
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(uriTone);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        NotificationChannel mNotificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(
                "11001", "NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_NAME",
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
        mNotificationChannel.enableLights(true);
        mNotificationChannel.setLightColor(Color.YELLOW);
        mNotificationChannel.enableVibration(true);
        mNotificationChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 400, 300, 200, 400});

        builder.setChannelId("11001");
        mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mNotificationChannel);
    }
    mNotificationManager.notify(id, builder.build());

}

private static PendingIntent getPendingIntent(Context context) {
    Intent mIntent = new Intent(context, MovieDailyReceiver.class);
    return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 1001, mIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
}

public void setAlarm(Context context) {
    cancelAlarm(context);
    AlarmManager mAlarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Calendar mCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    mCalendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 7);
    mCalendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    mCalendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        mAlarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,mCalendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,getPendingIntent(context));
    } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        mAlarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,mCalendar.getTimeInMillis(), getPendingIntent(context));
    }



    Toast.makeText(context, "Daily Notif ON", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

public void cancelAlarm(Context context) {
    AlarmManager mAlarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    mAlarmManager.cancel(getPendingIntent(context));

    Toast.makeText(context, "Daily Notif OFF", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent mIntent) {
    sendNotification(context, context.getString(R.string.DailyTitle),
            context.getString(R.string.DailyCheck), 1001);
}
```

}

**Here's my MovieUpcomingReminder:**

```
public class MovieUpcomingReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
private static int mNotifId = 2000;

private void sendNotification(Context context, String title, String mDesc, int id, ResultsItem mMovieResult) {
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(
            Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    Uri uriTone = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notifications_black_24dp)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(mDesc)
            .setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, android.R.color.transparent))
            .setVibrate(new long[]{1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000})
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(uriTone);

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel("11011",
                "NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_NAME", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
        notificationChannel.enableLights(true);
        notificationChannel.setLightColor(Color.YELLOW);
        notificationChannel.enableVibration(true);
        notificationChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 400, 300, 200, 400});
        builder.setChannelId("11011");
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
    }
    notificationManager.notify(id, builder.build());
}

private static PendingIntent getPendingIntent(Context context) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, MovieUpcomingReceiver.class);
    return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 1011, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
}

public void setAlarm(Context context, List<ResultsItem> mMovieResults) {
    int delay = 0;

    for (ResultsItem movie : mMovieResults) {
        cancelAlarm(context);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, MovieUpcomingReceiver.class);
        intent.putExtra("movietitle", movie.getTitle());
        intent.putExtra("movieid", movie.getId());
        intent.putExtra("movieposter", movie.getPhoto());
        intent.putExtra("moviemDescription", movie.getOverview());
        intent.putExtra("moviedate", movie.getReleaseDate());
        intent.putExtra("id", mNotifId);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,
                100, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 8);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(
                    AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                    calendar.getTimeInMillis() + delay,
                    AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,
                    pendingIntent
            );
        } else if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            alarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                    calendar.getTimeInMillis() + delay, pendingIntent);
        }
        mNotifId += 1;
        delay += 3000;
    }
    Toast.makeText(context, "Upcoming Notif ON", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}


@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String mMovieTitle = intent.getStringExtra("movietitle");
    int id = intent.getIntExtra("id", 0);
    ResultsItem mMovieResult = new ResultsItem();
    String mDesc = context.getString(R.string.todayRelease) + " : " +mMovieTitle;
    sendNotification(context, context.getString(R.string.app_name), mDesc, id, mMovieResult);

}

public void cancelAlarm(Context context) {
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.cancel(getPendingIntent(context));
    Toast.makeText(context, "Upcoming Notif OFF", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

}

**Here's my SettingPref:**

```
public class SettingPref extends AppCompatPref {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content, new MainPreferenceFragment()).commit();
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}

public static class MainPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment implements Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener {

    private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
    List<ResultsItem> mNotifList;
    MovieDailyReceiver mMovieDailyReceiver = new MovieDailyReceiver();
    MovieUpcomingReceiver mMovieUpcomingReceiver = new MovieUpcomingReceiver();
    SwitchPreference mSwitchReminder;
    SwitchPreference mSwitchToday;

    public class GetMovieTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... strings) {
            getData(strings[0]);
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
        String key = preference.getKey();
        boolean value = (boolean) newValue;
        if (key.equals(getString(R.string.todayreminder))) {
            if (value) {
                mMovieDailyReceiver.setAlarm(getActivity());
            } else {
                mMovieDailyReceiver.cancelAlarm(getActivity());
            }
        } else {
            if (value) {
                setReleaseAlarm();
            } else {
                mMovieUpcomingReceiver.cancelAlarm(getActivity());
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    private void setReleaseAlarm() {
        Date today = new Date();
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        String todaysDate = dateFormat.format(today);
        MainPreferenceFragment.GetMovieTask getDataAsync = new MainPreferenceFragment.GetMovieTask();
        getDataAsync.execute("https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?api_key=80077c53d53b7215a6c2f2120d065f81&primary_release_date.gte="+todaysDate+"&primary_release_date.lte="+todaysDate);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
        mNotifList = new ArrayList<>();
        mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
        mSwitchReminder = (SwitchPreference) findPreference(getString(R.string.todayreminder));
        mSwitchReminder.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(this);
        mSwitchToday = (SwitchPreference) findPreference(getString(R.string.todayRelease));
        mSwitchToday.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(this);
        Preference myPref = findPreference(getString(R.string.languagesets));
        myPref.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener() {
            public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
                startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCALE_SETTINGS));
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    public void getData(String url) {
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.getDefault());
        Date date = new Date();
        final String today = dateFormat.format(date);
        JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                try {
                    JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("results");

                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject data = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        ResultsItem movieItem = new ResultsItem();
                        movieItem.setTitle(data.getString("title"));
                        movieItem.setReleaseDate(data.getString("release_date"));
                        movieItem.setTitle(data.getString("title"));
                        movieItem.setOverview(data.getString("overview"));
                        movieItem.setOverview(data.getString("poster_path"));
                        if (data.getString("release_date").equals(today)) {
                            mNotifList.add(movieItem);
                        }
                    }
                    mMovieUpcomingReceiver.setAlarm(getActivity(), mNotifList);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                error.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
        mRequestQueue.add(request);
    }
}
```

}